# List NodeMetrics with client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

As we know,we can get node list by code:
`nodes, err := clientset.CoreV1().Nodes().List(metav1.ListOptions{})`
,the list option just like this:

```
metav1.ListOptions{
        FieldSelector: "spec.nodeName=" + node.Name,
        LabelSelector: labs.String(),
    }
```

But when I get Node metrics:`mc.MetricsV1beta1().NodeMetricses(metav1.NamespaceAll).List(metav1.ListOptions{})`

I don't know the list option is just about node or the NodeMetrics Struct itself.It confuses me long time.

Comment: `ListOptions` always applies to the object you are listing. In this case: node metrics.

Comment: But I want to list metrics of node that match the list option?How can I do it?This way can help me:```mc.MetricsV1beta1().NodeMetricses().Get("your node name", metav1.GetOptions{})```,but it is one by one,very slow!